# after a routine reboot, Google Play Services disappeared on stock 5.0.2 Moto E 2015

Tags: google-play-services

Been loving my 2nd-gen Moto E for the last month or 2. Rebooted it last night and when it came back Google Play Services was missing, i.e., no longer listed under Apps, no way to clear cache for it, no way to open Hangouts, Play Store, Gmail, Contacts, etc. Google account no longer listed under accounts, and can't add a new one.

For the record, I've only installed things from the Google Play Store and almost exclusively use Google apps (plus a few other big name things: Pandora, Vine, Dictionary.com, LastPass, Out of Milk, VLC, Power Toggles, Smart Launcher Pro).

Nothing changed between the last couple reboots. (Rant: This is the kind of bull that makes me hesitate to recommend Android phones to my non-techie Apple-prone friends and family.) I know I could do a factory reset, but given I've done nothing unusual, that's going to destroy my confidence in this phone.

Anyone seen anything similar? Where can I start?

EDIT: I just went ahead and did a factory reset. All was well for a couple weeks or so. Then one day this happened: [Gmail, Inbox, Messaging, Messenger work until try to open conversation -- crash](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/112327/106157)

Comment: I have a similar problem on a Zest T1 (random Chinese phone) installing them from apk brings them back (allowing uninstall upgrade) but the disappear on the next reboot...

Comment: I have the same problem on Zest T1, did you ever get it fixed @GertvandenBerg ?

Comment: @Frank: The "recent" Zest firmware has a Zest Apps (or something like that) app which, until the Play store have been selected, seems to freeze the Play store app