# Gmail, Inbox, Messaging, Messenger work until try to open conversation -- crash

Tags: crashes

Phone: stock 5.0.2 Moto E 2015

Randomly one day about 2 weeks ago I started getting popup notifications like:

> Unfortunately, Keep has stopped.

Same for Pocket, and Google Play Newsstand. Like, regularly. In spurts. Like one after the other. Disabling the apps in preferences and force-closing them makes no difference. Resetting them to factory or removing & reinstalling makes no difference. Trying to open those apps directly also leads only to that error.

At the same time I noticed that I could no longer click on notifications from Inbox and Hangouts. I could open the apps directly but they would stop as soon as I clicked on a conversation. I then tried and saw the same behavior with the older Messaging and newer Messenger. I see similar behavior with Calendar and Play books -- i.e., I can open the apps directly, but as soon as I try to open an entity (an event in Calendar or a book in Books), the app stops with the same dialog as above.

Clicking **Report** in the above-mentioned popup always led to a crash ... until this morning. The feedback app now works.

What else works: Chrome, Google Now, Play Music (I use it all day every day), and the Contacts/Phone apps all seem fine.

PS: This is the same phone I had to do a factory reset on after [after a routine reboot, Google Play Services disappeared on stock 5.0.2 Moto E 2015](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/108308/106157) unexplicably happened. Based on this, I'm starting to think that the flash memory is faulty and leading to random corruption. It's the only theory I've got.

Comment: The moto phones after lenovo's acquisition have become really terrible.  All the first generation moto devices were really awesome but users of the second generation are facing a lot of issues.